# guidelines to handle missing categorical feature values in Random Forest Regressor

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

What is a general guideline to handle missing categorical feature values when using Random Forest Regressor (or any ensemble learner for that matter)? I know that scikit learn has impute function (like mean...strategy or proximity) to impute missing values (numerical). But, how does one handle missing categorical value : Like Industry (oil, computer, auto, **None**), major(bachelors, masters, doctoral, **None**).

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Note that you've stated that "any suggestion is appreciated", and someone actually answered you. If the answer is useful, you can upvote or accept it; if not, you can help the poster by explaining why not.

Answer (score 1):

Breiman and Cutler, the inventors of Random Forest, suggest two possible strategies (see http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#missing1):

> Random forests has two ways of replacing missing values. The first way
>   is fast. If the mth variable is not categorical, the method computes
>   the median of all values of this variable in class j, then it uses
>   this value to replace all missing values of the mth variable in class
>   j. If the mth variable is categorical, the replacement is the most
>   frequent non-missing value in class j. These replacement values are
>   called fills.
>
> The second way of replacing missing values is computationally more
>   expensive but has given better performance than the first, even with
>   large amounts of missing data. It replaces missing values only in the
>   training set. It begins by doing a rough and inaccurate filling in of
>   the missing values. Then it does a forest run and computes
>   proximities.

Alternatively, leaving your label variable aside for a minute, you could train a classifier on rows that have non-null values for the categorical variable in question, using all of your features in the classifier. Then use this classifier to predict values for the categorical variable in question in your 'test set'. Armed with a more complete data set, you can now return to the task of predicting values for your original label variable.